# Make [if-then] a synonym of [if-statement]

Tags: support, tags, synonym-request

The [if-then](/questions/tagged/if-then) tag seems a bit pointless, but is being used. Could we please either:

1. Burninate it; or
2. Make it a synonym for [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement)?

(This came to my attention through https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2285785 where user [Dariusz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1961634/dariusz) was giving the tag [if-then](/questions/tagged/if-then) the tag excerpt "do not use this tag; use `if-statement` which is more general". This seems sensible to me.)

Comment: Does `[if-statement]` really serve a valid purpose?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: I haven't looked at that aspect of it at all, to tell the truth

Comment: In some languages `if ... then ... else ...` is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: True... I wasn't thinking about that. The "then" part is still not necessarily accurate. e.g. in Python you get both the `if` statement and the `if` expression (`b if a else c`). Hmm.